# Repaint method not working after calling

Tags: java, repaint

I am creating an app to implement an algorithm, but before that i needed get the paint method working
 I have a button, upon clicking it i am calling the test method, i am getting the output "values set" from the println but the repaint method is not getting executed.

But the same thing is working in an other simple app.

Any help would be great

BTW i am electronics guy so I don't know much of programming

```
This is the class for painting
`

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

    private java.util.List<Rectangle> rectangles = 
                                new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public Draw() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    }

    public void test(){
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10,10,10,10));
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(20,20,10,10));
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(30,30,10,10));
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(40,40,10,10));
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(50,50,10,10));       
         rectangles.add(new Rectangle(60,60,10,10));
         this.setValues(rectangles);
         System.out.println("in test class");
    }

    public void setValues(java.util.List<Rectangle> rectangles) {
        this.rectangles = rectangles;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("values set!!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(5, 5, 100, 300);
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y,rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        }
        System.out.println("WORKING");
    }   
}

`
```

The class for GUI

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Design extends JFrame{

    Draw Draw = new Draw();
    static HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

        public void DisplayGUI(){

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.setContentPane(content);
.//Contains code that adds different buttons to Different panels
.
.
.
.           content.add(Draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(775,600);
            frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

The main Class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Program extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Design().DisplayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

The Handler Class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

    private String string ="";
    ExampleOne ExampleOne = new ExampleOne();
    Draw draw = new Draw();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        string = ((JButton) event.getSource()).getActionCommand();

        if(string == "Example 1"){
            ExampleOne.run();
        }
    }
}

class ExampleOne{
    Draw draw = new Draw();
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("in example one class"); 
        draw.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Method names and variables should be `lowerCamelCase` for readability. I don't see the class Draw being used anywhere besides the initialization.

Comment: @Nfear edited the post now

Comment: You are setting the values of a panel which isn't added to the frame. In `ExampleOne` you are using `Draw draw = new Draw();`. It should be the panel that was added to the frame previously. Try to debug to see what happens at each step.

Comment: @Nfear got my mistake now, what you are saying is right. But how shall I pass the panel which was created at first in the design class to a different class.